# wordpress unable to access a page

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a wordpress site on my local server. I am able to access all the pages but only `http://samplesite.com/wp-admin/theme-editor.php`

it shows

```
   You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.
```

I changed the directory permissions to 777 using chmod. Still it shows the same thing.

I am able to access all other pages like `/wp-admin` all post links, i can install new themes, plugins create posts edit, add widgets etc.

Comment: i have one.  i have all like, mod_rewrite.c also

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind this, is your user permissions. Like wordpress assign some permissions to different types of users. Like everything is allow for admin but other users have limits. Maybe you're not the admin or You're using a plugin which block it.

Deactivate all the plugins then try again. If this error is because of any plugin then `/wp-admin/theme-editor.php` file will start opening correctly.

Comment: Yes. This is a WordPress error message, i.e. it's issued by WordPress's access and permissions system, not by htaccess problems or file permissions, generally.

Comment: I am the root user,  there is no other user. As i said its on my own local server. I deactivated all the plugins and tried still the same messsage `You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.` ALso i moved the plugins directory and tried still the same error.

Comment: Firstly It is not a server error. I found [this](http://wpquestions.com/question/showChrono/id/8073), check there hope it should solve your problem.

Comment: but will my posts be wiped out. Actually i have wp_user_roles also in my table wp_options.

Comment: Firstly Export your wp data (including post, categories, tags etc.) then and then reinstall using manual method. But wp has auto reinstall option in `wp-admin -> updates` if wordpress has new version you update from that place, there was also a option for reinstall use it...